# Adding custom rules in PMD - class not found issue

Tags: java, pmd

I am trying to execute this example shown here

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.0/customizing/howtowritearule.html

WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule class not found is shown [one of the standard issue for beginners i believe]

Method tried :

```
1) cd pmd-5.3.0
2) created WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule.java and ruleset.xml as per shown in the page.
3) javac -cp [all the required jar files seperated by ; since it is windows pc ] WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule.java
4) bin/pmd.bat -d [code on which pmd has to check the rule] -f xml -R ruleset.xml
```

the above steps are giving me no class found error,here developer has commented saying these steps work 
[ http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/discussion/188192/thread/7a34d224/ ]

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

I tried adding class file directly to classpath as well
Other methods tried :

```
1) compiled the WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule.java file and got the .class file.
2) created a jar using jar -cf jar_name jar_file command
3) added that jar file in the class path , using set CLASSPATH and also tried adding directly in the batch file used to run PMD i.e. pmd.bat
```

please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

Had to set CLASSPATH separately using

```
set CLASSPATH=path\to\my\classfile
```

and then in the batch i had to add %CLASSPATH% , otherwise using -cp was resetting the classpath i guess. This worked for me.

Thanks